# VUE-JS - CHECKBOX V-MODEL

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, http-post

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SHiZ.jpg)    Hi Everyone Newbie at VUE.JS
I have a Checkboxes for MODULES and FUNCTIONS
I want to insert a Functions for every MODULE I have

Here's my sample code

```
<label> Modules:</label>
          <li v-for="subModule1 in subModules" :key="subModule1.id">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="dataModules" :value="subModule1" />
            
              {{subModule1}}<br>
```

[enter image description here][1]
                    {{subFunction}}

```
            </div>
```

Comment: This is one my FUNCTIONS

<div v-for="subFunction in subFunctions" :key="subFunction.id"> 
                  <input type="checkbox" checked="false" v-model="dataFunctions" :value="subFunction.id" />
                  
                    {{subFunction.Functions}}

                </div>

Comment: Can you provide a bit more explanation about you problem?

Comment: example sir

if I checked the ADD checkbox in MODULE 1

Module 2 ADD checkbox will not be checked 


In my situations ADD checkbox in MODULE 1 if I checked Both MODULE 1 and MODULE 2 have a check in ADD CHECKBOX

Comment: ok so you have let say list of modules [A,B,C,D,E,F] and each of these modules have sob list like [Aa,Ab],[Ba,Bb] so right now the proble is if you check Aa it will check Ba am right

Comment: Module 1 [A, B, C]
Module 2 [A, B, C]

Comment: yes If I check A from module 1

the other A from module 2 will have a check 

so basically thats my problem .

Comment: well thats because they are bind to same property you could use some thing like bellow answer

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is to create component like bellow I am not sure it will be a perfect solution but it should work atleast

```
<template>
   <div>
      <div v-for="module in modules" :key="module.text">
        <h3>{{module.text}}</h3>
        <ul>
            <li 
                v-for="subModule in module.subModules" 
                :key="subModule.text"
            >
               {{subModule.text}}
               <input type="checkbox" v-model="subModule.value"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'Example',
   data(){
      return {
           modules:[
               {
                    text:"Module 1",
                    subModules:[
                        {
                            text:"1-A",
                            value:false,
                        },
                        {
                            text:"1-b",
                            value:false,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text:"Module 2",
                    subModules:[
                        {
                            text:"2-A",
                            value:false,
                        },
                        {
                            text:"2-b",
                            value:false,
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

With this you are binding with array key is text but you can change it to something else and if you want to add new module or sub module just add it to array and it should be added to ui
If module dont pick new added items you something like deep copy and assign new array to module

Comment: Thank you sir, Appreciate your time
but still not working at my side

maybe this time I'm not going use V-MODEL